# Eclipse string literal line wrapping

Tags: eclipse

When I run the Formatter it indents string literal lines all the way to the last line of the variable name, even if that exceeds the column guide, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Undesired line-wrapping behavior]

Ideally, I want all of the lines to be wrapped similar to the way the first line is wrapped, with just a couple of tabs (or 1 tab if possible). I've changed all the Formatter settings for assignment and binary expression and it doesn't affect the Formatter's line wrapping behavior.

Is there a way to make Eclipse wrap lines like NetBeans or maybe with some plugin?

Here's what my Formatter settings are for Line Wrapping:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Plugins

1. **[Eclipse Colorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/)**

has an "Enhanced and fixed word wrapping mode".

2. **[Eclipse Word-Wrap](https://ahtik.com/blog/projects/eclipse-word-wrap/)**

is dedicated to word wrapping and might do the job.

## Customization

Here's how and where you do it in Eclipse: `Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter`, then click the `Edit` button and select the `Comments` tab. After that, the same place, you can select the `Line Wrapping` tab and the `Indentation` tab. You can also set margins and tab sizes in `Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors` by editing the `Displayed Tab Width`

I'll note that the Eclipse version should be [Eclipse Project Neon (4.6) M4](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M4/) or higher because Eclipse 4.6 came with some updated word wrapping out of the box.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try it out?

Comment: I will try soon Thank you

Comment: I noticed you've tried it out and I guess it's working the way you like. However, may I ask you why you posted the same screenshot in the question and the answer? Don't really understand why

Comment: It was a mistake and I didn't know how to take it back. Can you remove it? I wasn't able to make Colorer change the way line wrapping works and the settings aren't have the desired effect.

Comment: I've updated my answer to further help you out if possible

Comment: It is not working. Have you tried to make any of these work yourself??

Comment: It's hard to try them out if you don't have the problem. But seeing the documentation of the plugins or just looking at the name, one would guess it's designed as a solution.

Comment: None of these work. However the bounty was awarded automatically. I welcome any new answers.